# Changing the CSS in a Infragistics WebDataGrid

Tags: css, html, infragistics

I am trying to change the css (basically just the colour of the header, rows etc) of the web data grid. I've been searching for a while and the only options I've come across are:

1. Modify the Infragistics.css file located at
   /Content/Infragistics/css - doubt this is the right way of doing it.
   File is huge and not really maintainable.
2. Download and apply themes - think this is applicable only for
   asp.net and more over this isn't exactly flexible.

Guessing there is another way of doing this. Anu suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: The whole point of CSS is that is cascades, aka you can override existing styles. That's why they're called Cascading Style Sheets. Perhaps have a read up on how CSS works, try and implement some new rules to override the existing ones, and come back here if you're still having problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little more searching, and a little help from the Chrome page source, I found out that the selectors to be used are slightly different from the regular format.

For example to select the rows : `#igGrid1 > tbody > tr` where `#igGrid1` corresponds to the id of the Infragrid.

This [page](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/engineering/archive/2010/08/25/webdatagrid-css-styling-guide.aspx) gives a few more examples of the different kind of selectors needed to access the Infra grid elements.